# Sql Server. From condicional

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Tengo una consulta algo especial, necesito seleccionar la tabla principal de los datos dependiendo la con condición. Mi código hasta el momento va así:

```
Declare @table Sysname,
Declare @temp table ( [Codigo] [int] NULL,
                      [Fecha] [Datetime] NULL, )
If getdate())<2021 insert into @temp; Select * From Historia

Set @tabla=Case When Then year(getdate())<2021 '@temp' Else 'Actual' End
Select * From @tabla activa Where month(activa.fecha)=month(getdate())
```

La verdad he probado muchas alternativas pero hasta el momento no he tenido existo.

Muchas gracias por compartir sus conocimientos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes valerte de la ejecución de SQL Dinámico, mediante la función [`execute()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql), que recibe una cadena con una sentencia SQL válida, por ejemplo, una sentencia `select` que puedes construir al vuelo según tus condiciones.

Además, debes ajustar la sintaxis y otros errores presentes en el script que propones, como la forma de determinar el nombre de la tabla, en *TransactSQL*, lo que pones en tu pregunta no es válido, además que varías el nombre de la variable.

Según puedo interpretar, lo que buscas es lo siguiente:

```
declare @table Sysname;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

if year(getdate()) < 2021 
  set @table= 'Historia';
else 
  set @table= 'Actual';

set @sql = 'select * from ' + @table + ' as activa where month(activa.fecha) = month(getdate())';

--esto si quieres "ver" la sentencia generada
print @sql;  

execute (@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar Exec() para armar tu select como un string y luego ejecutarlo:

```
Declare @table Sysname;
Set @table = CASE WHEN year(getdate())<2021 THEN  'Historia' Else 'Actual' END
exec('select * from ' + @table + ' activa Where month(activa.fecha)=month(getdate()')
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por su respuesta. La verdad es que la consulta es a modo de prueba, pues depende solo de un factor para que muchas columnas cambien de fuente, incluso hay muchas que realizan una comparación de texto encerrado en ' ' se puedo unirlas con +' '+, pero son casi 100 lineas de opciones de consulta; ¿usted sabe de otra opción?, muchas gracias